# WS02 SSO store credentials in database

Tags: single-sign-on, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

We are building an App store for our SAAS platform and using WS02 ESB.

We are using the WS02 Identity server.  Once a user connects an APP with our platform, we are not sure how to store their login info.  For security reasons, we obviously do not want to store their username/passwords in our DB for any particular app.  Using SSO, is there a global WS02 solution to authenticate users, perhaps using tokens? Any help will be much appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Currently WSO2 Identity server supports various SSO authentication methods, Including token based authentication. You can refer to [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Single+Sign-On) to get to know about supported methods and use them.

The recommended method for doing this is using SAML SSO. You can follow [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AS530/Using+SSO+with+Web+Applications) link to do that.

Hope this helps.